# Webhook from Wix to Zapier

Tags: javascript, json, webhooks

I am trying to send a webhook from WIX to Zapier from a custom form. I am getting a success message from Zapier that they have received a webhook but there is not data in the webhook to read. Below is my code so if someone could give me some tips and tricks that would be great!

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';


export function button1_click(event,$w){

  const url = "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/2560455/a9eoqe/";

 let firstName = $w("#firstName").value;
 let lastName = $w("#lastName").value;
 let contactEmail = $w("#contactEmail").value;
 let contactCompany =$w ("#contactCompany").value;
 let contactNumber = $w("#contactNumber").value;
 let contactStaffN = $w("#contactStaffN").value;
 let contactComments = $w("#contactComments").value;
 let data = {"firstName":firstName, "lastName":lastName, "contactEmail":contactEmail, "contactCompany":contactCompany, "contactNumber":contactNumber, "contactStaffN":contactStaffN, "contactComments":contactComments};
    console.log(data);

    var bodyData = JSON.stringify(data);

    fetch (url, {method: 'post' ,body: 'bodyData'})
    .then((httpResponse)=>{
        if(httpResponse.ok){
            return httpResponse.json();
        }else{
            return Promise.reject("Fetchdidnotsucceed");
        }
    })
    .then(json=>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
        $w("#button1").disable();
        $w("#button1").label="Thanks for submitting the data!";
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: {method: 'post' ,body: 'bodyData'}) has bodyData in quotes. it should not be.

Comment: From what I've read, Zapier cannot integrate with Wix yet, only Wix Answers which is for the Wix Support Team. :(